# How to Create new div for each loop in C#

Tags: c#, html

I am using HTML with c#. How i can create new div for each loop in the while to be able to make the designee as i want

my html code:

```
< div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="blog-post2">
        <div class="post-img"><a href = "#" >< img src="images/blog-img16.jpg" alt=" "></a></div>
        <div class="post-text">
        <div class="date">
        <span class="post-date">26</span>
        <span class="month">Oct<br>2017</span>
        </div>
        <h4><a href = "#" > Title </a></h4>
        <p>Detelse</p>
        <a href = "#" class="read-more">detelse</a>
        </div></div>

        </div>
```

my C# code:

```
SqlCommand cmd_check2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd_check2.CommandText = @"SELECT
                                  [title_news]
                                  FROM [website_DB].[dbo].[long_news_T] where id = 1";

        //cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_mail", txtUserName.Text);


        DataTable df2 = WebTbi_V1._1.func.general.GetData(cmd_check2, Label1, "website");

        foreach (DataRow row2 in df2.Rows)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("- - - Row - - -");
            foreach (var item_1 in row2.ItemArray)
            {

               my for code ????


            }

            test.InnerHtml = html;
        }
```

i want create a div for my news depending on result query

i need help

Comment: Using Asp or creating a Html text?

Comment: For asp, Either a repeater, or add asp component programatically into a panel, or Something like razor. If it's for an Html text like email content etc Razor by far the easyest solution. Each of those solution can be demonstrate in a 2 page tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

With a little googling you can find many and many samples for this problem

```
 foreach (var item_1 in row2.ItemArray)
 {
     HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
     myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12");    

     /*
      You need to do same thing for every div you have inside 
      the parent div, and simply add them to parent div and 
      finally add your parent div to a Panel or Page or 
      any other place holder you have
    */
    myPanel.Controls.Add(myDiv);
}
```

You might then need to pay attention for the event, where you generate your controls

Comment: As you mention a Panel, I will add that `asp:Panel` generate a div so you can directly work with it's style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text template for it as one of the ways.

Try https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp for example. Just create HTML template and use `{{#each}}` tag for loop.

In the future, it will be easier for you to change the template and as for me it's easier to make markupю